# Alter WordPress post title and body in view mode only

Tags: php, wordpress

I am looking for the way how to alter a WordPress post title and body when it is displayed to a normal user. But not in any other context, ie in admin module.

The task at hand is to fetch a query parameter, carry out some calls to external webservice and database operations and replace some text in both title and body. The `<title>` tag should also contain the changed title.

I do not look for a plugin solution, but rather were I should include a php file with all the code that does all the necessary processing.

My expectation was that I don't have to deeply meddle with the theme files. Of course, I could inject my code in the respective theme's `page.php` or `content.php` file. But I'd like to do it in less intrusive way, for example by including my `functions_custom.php` file in the top of `functions.php`, and this file would contain a collection of functions and `add_filter()` calls to hook those functions on certain events. Is that possible to achieve my goal that way?

This is my first attempt:

```
<?php
function alter_title( $title, $id = null ) {
    return 'Altered title: ' . $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'alter_title', 10, 2 );
?>
```

This causes change in all the post titles in all contexts, including the post list in the Dashboard. But I need it to be altered only in view context (this also does not influence the text used in the `<title>` tag). Perhaps I can sniff this context somehow, and engage the alteration only when the view mode is detected?

Comment: What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?

Comment: @robert, I expanded the question now.

Answer (score 0):

While ago I needed to do similar thing and my fast and short workaround was to have an "API" (

1. Created a template for that specific post type and using PHP generated a post ID indicator:

   `$post = get_post(); echo "var post_id = '".$post->ID."';";`
2. I created a custom API  that "takes" $_POST request with "post_id" param and it would fetch adequate/custom (in your case a content that will be shown to the user) content from database for the post with the post_id from $_POST request.
3. Then for every post there would be an ajax request to that API which sends post_id and fetches all the needed info (in your case post title and body) and then using eg. jQuery
   `.append()` would populate post title with response post title and body too, respectively.

Also, if you'd like to avoid a extra request than you should try to generate that 'user-visible' content with PHP.  That would mean you need to collect the content before loading the page and `echo`it in the place of default content.

I suppose you should create a function in functions.php that takes an $post->ID and fetches title and body from the database. Then you should call that function on every loop and single post template, if you understand me.

Comment: That means an extra request (delayed one, too) for the content, and also directly editing the template. I hoped to avoid that.

Comment: I am still hoping for less intrusive way. Editing the theme files is hard to maintain if switching to another theme later.

Answer (score 0):

`is_admin()` will return `true` if you are viewing an admin page.
So you could do this:

```
function alter_title( $title, $id = null ) {
    if(is_admin()){
        return $title;
    }else{
        return 'Altered title: ' . $title;
    }
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'alter_title', 10, 2 );
```